# for loop doesnt return anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I have recently added some facebook api calls to my app. When the user visits a specific profile page, it does a call to the facebook api and updates the posts for that page.

Though, when the user uses the search engine, it only pulls the old posts from my data base - Because the facebook API call is only being made from inside the user profile. This means the search engine is out of date with the user page. I'd like the search engine to remain up to date.

So I am editing this function, on the search page, to check to see if the user has linked facebook, and if they have, to update the posts from the search page.

Here is my code and how it works with comments - The new part, the for() loop, doesnt return the new data(bands).

```
const getBands = async (location) => {
    const token = await getTokenSilently();

    //Get Local Bands
    try {
        let response = await fetch(`/api/autoquotegenerators/homeBands/${location[0]}/${location[1]}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            }
        })
        const newBands = await response.json()


        //Updating Facebook Posts if the band has integrated FB - This is the part that doesnt work.
        for(let i=0; i < newBands.length; i++){
            if(newBands[i].fbData){
                //Hold onto Old Posts - This includes the native posts from my website.
                let oldPosts = newBands[i].posts

                //Get Fb Posts
                let fbFormattedPosts = []
                let response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${newBands[i].fbData.pageId}/feed?access_token=${newBands[i].fbData.pageAccessTokenLong}`)
                let fbPosts = await response.json()
                fbPosts.data.forEach(post => {
                    if(post.message){
                        let fbPostObject = {
                            type: 'text',
                            data: post.message,
                            link: `http://www.facebook.com/${post.id}`,
                            date: post.created_time,
                            postId: post.id,
                            rockOn: []
                        }
                        fbFormattedPosts.push(fbPostObject)
                    }
                })

                //Combine All New Posts with Old Posts - And Check to make sure there are no duplicates.
                let newPosts = [ 
                    ...oldPosts, 
                    ...fbFormattedPosts
                        .filter(({postId}) => 
                        !oldPosts
                            .find(post => post.postId == postId)),
                ]

                //Save the new posts to the Band Object
                newBands[i].posts = newPosts

                return newBands[i]
            }else {
                return newBands[i]
            }

        }

        //Set The Band Objects to React State
        if(newBands !== []){
            setBands(newBands)
        }

        //Get Tour Bands
        response = await fetch(`/api/autoquotegenerators/tourBands/${location[0]}/${location[1]}`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            }
        })
        const newTourBands = await response.json();
        if(newTourBands !== []){
            setTourBands(newTourBands)
        }

        setAllBands([ ...newBands, ...newTourBands])

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some logging statements within the for loop to insure the functions are being run. Let's see what section within the for loop isn't running. For all we know right now, it's failing out immediately with the `if(newBands[i].fbData)` check and returning the object without running anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I figured it out.. Took me a bit - I didnt need to return the band object. I just needed to update the posts. I removed the return statement, and it worked like a charm. Thanks!